# Playing a video via script does not work on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html5-video

What I want to do is quite simple. Playing a video via script. That's it. My code works well on PC, however not on Android. 
The weird thing is that after I tap a video element to play the video and tap it again to pause it, my code works well.., which means playing the video is executed by the server-side js method.
I just assume that I need to add some extra information for code on Android to work in a way I expected. The code as follows.

```html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <video id="video-player" width="640" height="480" preload="auto">
    <source src="assets/test_movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

  <!-- import script after DOM is ready -->
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="/frontapp.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```

```js

```
(function(){

  var socket = io();

  // store video dom element in application memory
  var video = document.getElementById('video-player');

  // listen socket
  socket.on('player trigger', function(data){
    //playMovie(video);
    video.play();
    console.log('hi there from server');
    document.getElementById('heading').innerText = makeid();
  });

  // method to change text
  function makeid()
  {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
  }

})();
```

```

```serverside

```
**// Setup basic express server
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('../..')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 7000;



server.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});

// Routing
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/myapp'));

// method from server
setInterval(function(){
  io.emit('player trigger');
  console.log('io.emit:)');
}, 5000);
```

```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an expected behaviour and there is no way to make it work the way you want it.

On mobile devices by design only user actions can start video and audio playback. That means that `video.play();` has to be called in click handler (you can use `setTimeout` in a handler though).

This is to restrict unwanted data tansfers to avoid unnecessary costs.
Read more on that in [this article](https://www.aerserv.com/why-does-video-autoplay-on-mobile-devices-not-work/).